# Incorrect error message is displayed by "ModelState.AddModelError" in Asp.Net Core Razore Pages

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages, modelstate

In my `OnPost` method bellow, I check if the field `CoursePrice` is numeric :

```
public IActionResult OnPost(IFormFile imgCourseUp, IFormFile demoFileName) {
    float num;
    if (!float.TryParse(Course.CoursePrice.ToString(), out num))
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError("", "Put a Valid Number..");
        return Page();
    }
}
```

When I put an invalid number for example: "123kk", enything went wrong. I mean the method `float.TryParse(Course.CoursePrice.ToString(), out num)` works correctly and there is nothing wrong with  my codes. But when I run the project and  put invalid number, the error message would be something else! for example in this part `ModelState.AddModelError("", "Put a Valid Number..")`, I said the error message must be **Put a Valid Number..**, but it showed me this error : **The value '123l' is not valid for قیمت دوره**

So anyone have any ideas?

And this is my View Razore :

```
<div class="form-group">
   <label>قیمت دوره </label>
   <input class="form-control" type="text" asp-for="@Model.Course.CoursePrice" value="0" />
   <p class="help-block">لطفا فقط عدد وارد کنید</p>
 </div>

 <div class="form-group">
     <div asp-validation-summary="All"></div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Could it be that you are running another validation framework in parallel? E.g. is there a data annotation set for the property, or are you using fluentvalidation?

Answer (score 0):

The first parameter of ModelState.AddModelError should be the name of your model property, so it knows in what property the error occurred.

Try changing the line `ModelState.AddModelError("", "Put a Valid Number..");` to `ModelState.AddModelError(nameof(Course.CoursePrice), "Put a Valid Number..");`

Full code:

```
public IActionResult OnPost(IFormFile imgCourseUp, IFormFile demoFileName) {
    float num;
    if (!float.TryParse(Course.CoursePrice.ToString(), out num))
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError(nameof(Course.CoursePrice), "Put a Valid Number..");
        return Page();
    }
}
```

Comment: I know exaxtly what you're  saying.  I've tried the way you said before, it didn't make any difference!

Comment: Maybe it is appending the new error to a list of existing errors.. what happens if you call ModelState["CoursePrice"].Errors.Clear(); before the call to ModelState.AddModelError?

Comment: I just tried ModelState["CoursePrice"].Errors.Clear(), but again showed me the same error! :)